# IntelliSense suggestions for method parameter input

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reflection, intellisense, visual-studio-extensions

I have static class as container for some static strings:

```
public static class Constants
    {
        public static string ERROR_MESSAGE_LOGIN= "Unable to login with {0}";
        public static string ERROR_MESSAGE_SEND_MAIL= "Unagle to send mail to {0}";

        public static string GetFormatedString(string constantName, object [] params)
        {
            return 
            string.Format((string)typeof(Constants).GetField(constantName).GetValue(null),params);
        }
    }
```

As you can see I want to return formatted string, that based on name provided. And it is seems to work. However, when I writing method call in some other class I want that it give me list of suggestion for first parameter that contains "ERROR_MESSAGE_LOGIN" and "ERROR_MESSAGE_SEND_MAIL".

I know that I can create enum with those name or just use it like

```
Constants.GetFormatedString(Constants.ERROR_MESSAGE_SEND_MAIL, someparams);
```

But is there any way to tell method there is list of string parameters that you accept and show it to user in Visual Studio `IntelliSense`?

Thank you.

Comment: OK, let's see if I understand you correctly. You have some kind of a `dropdown` menu. you want to show a list of suggestions when the user type something. These suggestions are based on a class public fields? right? and this class only! you mean the suggestions source will be based on the class `Constants` public fields.

Comment: Yes, so basically, when user type "GetFormatedString(" it should show some kind menu in VisualStudio which contains list of those public static string parameters from that class.

Comment: In visual studio! not in the UI. So it's not a drop-down menu in the UI. You meant Visual Studio `Intellisense`?

Comment: Yes, in VS. Well I was not sure how to call it so I used "autosuggestion/drop down". But idea is to have it during development. So someone start to type the method name and it should show available params, but not list of params like (string s, int i). A list of values that can be inputed for parameter "string s", of cause I dont want to limit it so it can input some other string, but method should show that "you most likely want to use ERROR_MESSAGE_LOGIN or ERROR_MESSAGE_SEND_MAIL"

Comment: Do you know that you can use the operator `nameof` to obtain a member name of a class? if you typed `nameof(Constants.` the intelliSense will give you the suggestions that you are asking. Try it, if it didn't go as you like, then you may need to play around with visual studio extensnios